# how to split multiple nested dictionaries inside a list inside multiple dataframe columns without creating duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
   column1                                   column2                                 column3                                   column4
0        1  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]  {'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value11'}  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
1        2  [{'key1': 'value3'}, {'key2': 'value4'}]  {'key1': 'value12', 'key2': 'value13'}  [{'key1': 'value3'}, {'key2': 'value4'}]
2        3  [{'key1': 'value5'}, {'key2': 'value6'}]  {'key1': 'value14', 'key2': 'value15'}  [{'key1': 'value5'}, {'key2': 'value6'}]
.
.
```

I am trying to split column2 and column4 into columns, to look like this

```
col1     col2_key1        col2_key2     col3                                       col4_key1    col4_key2
1          value1           value2        {'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value11'}    value1       value2
2          value3           value4        {'key1': 'value12', 'key2': 'value13'}   value3     value4
.
.
```

Initially i was doing this , creating a lot of duplicates

```
dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(x) for k, x in df.pop('column2').items()}
df = df.join(pd.concat(dfs).add_prefix('column2_').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)

dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(x) for k, x in df.pop('column4').items()}
df = df.join(pd.concat(dfs).add_prefix('column4_').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then i used `json_normalize` giving me some weird datarame

```
df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x[0]) if isinstance(x[0], dict) else x[0])
df['column4'] = df['column4'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x[0]) if isinstance(x[0], dict) else x[0])
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'column1': [1, 2, 3],
    'column2': [[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}],
                [{'key1': 'value3'}, {'key2': 'value4'}],
                [{'key1': 'value5'}, {'key2': 'value6'}]],
    'column3': [{'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value11'},
                {'key1': 'value12', 'key2': 'value13'},
                {'key1': 'value14', 'key2': 'value15'}],
    'column4': [[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}],
                [{'key1': 'value3'}, {'key2': 'value4'}],
                [{'key1': 'value5'}, {'key2': 'value6'}]],
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

'''
dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(x) for k, x in df.pop('column2').items()}
df = df.join(pd.concat(dfs).add_prefix('column2_').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)

dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(x) for k, x in df.pop('column4').items()}
df = df.join(pd.concat(dfs).add_prefix('column4_').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
'''
# Apply pd.json_normalize on column2 and column4
df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x[0]) if isinstance(x[0], dict) else x[0])
df['column4'] = df['column4'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x[0]) if isinstance(x[0], dict) else x[0])

# Print the modified DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: How was the DataFrame originally created: from a json response and using `pd.json_normalize`?  If that is the case you should be able to normalize the nested data by using the `record_path` and `meta` params as shown in the second to last example in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('column2').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({f'column2_{k}': v for d in x for k, v in d.items()}))], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('column4').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({f'column4_{k}': v for d in x for k, v in d.items()}))], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   column1                                 column3 column2_key1 column2_key2 column4_key1 column4_key2
0        1  {'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value11'}       value1       value2       value1       value2
1        2  {'key1': 'value12', 'key2': 'value13'}       value3       value4       value3       value4
2        3  {'key1': 'value14', 'key2': 'value15'}       value5       value6       value5       value6
```